# ElasticSearch: request does not support [script_fields]

Tags: elasticsearch, flow-framework

I am trying to run ElasticSearch query to calculate a distance.

- Version of ElasticSearch is **1.7.2** and Java 1.7.0_79.
- Using PHP Framework TYPO3 Flow
- With [Neos ElasticSearch Adapter](https://github.com/Flowpack/Flowpack.ElasticSearch.ContentRepositoryAdaptor)

**Description:**

I have list of companies that are retrieved by ElasticSearch. User can search for a company by it's name and location. Here the location is the problem. When I search by location I am loosing my pagination.

Example Situation:

1. Set itemsPerPage of pagination to 10
2. Run search -> I can see i.e. 10 items and no pagination
3. Set itemsPerPage of pagination to 2 -> expected result is 5 pages
4. 2 items are listed and no pagination

Template of pagination:

```
{namespace search=TYPO3\TYPO3CR\Search\ViewHelpers}
<search:widget.paginate query="{searchQuery}" as="results" configuration="{'itemsPerPage': 2}">
    <ts:render path="searchResultRenderer" context="{searchResults: results}"/>
</search:widget.paginate>
```

Java error:

```
 org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [typo3cr-1444378386] request does not support [script_fields]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parseQuery(IndexQueryParserService.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.count.TransportCountAction.shardOperation(TransportCountAction.java:187)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.count.TransportCountAction.shardOperation(TransportCountAction.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction$AsyncBroadcastAction$1.run(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ElasticSearch configuration.yml:

```
# The following settings are absolutely required for the CR adaptor to work

script.file: on
script.inline: sandbox
script.indexed: sandbox

script.engine.groovy.inline: sandbox
script.engine.groovy.indexed: sandbox

script.groovy.sandbox.class_whitelist: java.util.LinkedHashMap
script.groovy.sandbox.receiver_whitelist:  java.util.Iterator, java.lang.Object, java.util.Map, java.util.Map$Entry
script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true

# the following settings are well-suited for smaller ElasticSearch instances (e.g. as long as you can stay on one host)
index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

The query I run is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_all": []
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "__parentPath": "/sites/project"
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "__workspace": [
                  "live"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "__typeAndSupertypes": "Project:Entry"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_hidden": true
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "_hiddenBeforeDateTime": {
                  "gt": "now"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "_hiddenAfterDateTime": {
                  "lt": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": "doc['coordinates'].distanceInKm(52.39266079999999,9.768640199999936)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the search URL you're sending the query to? It should not play a big role but Neos is supposed to be `...supporting ElasticSearch Version 1.2.x and 1.3.x and 1.4.x`

Comment: In general the ElasticSearch adaptor works fine with more recent versions (1.5.x - 1.7.x) of ES as well, so it's not that. I guess it's some configuration problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an error in the URL, something as simple as not using the `_search` endpoint for instance.

Comment: Search works. I am getting results but when I use query for `TYPO3\TYPO3CR\Search\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper` and use **itemsPerPage**, I am getting same or less number of items(results) as set up limit and without pagination. That is correct in the case there is exactly i.e. 10 items. If i change it to 2 itemsPerPage, I have only 2 results and no pagination again.

Comment: That is happening only in case I am using script_fields.

Comment: @Val I am not sure about the internals of ES, according to the docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html the groovy sandboxing is disabled AND is deprecated. Could it be that it's just not recognized as sandboxed despite `script.engine.groovy.inline: sandbox` being set? So maybe using one of the sandboxed languages could work?

Comment: Ah, never mind me, the error seems to be higher level, so even before checking for sandboxing. Indeed more like an URL problem

Comment: The reason I mentioned the URL issue, it's because the only case this can happen (according to the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/3a0d1841d9dc99b752d13118ea303f1497c28fc0/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/IndexQueryParserService.java#L233)) is when querying an index directly, i.e. not its `_search` endpoint

Comment: This is the URL I am calling http://localhost:9200/typo3cr/_search

Comment: Ah, good to know, yeah I expected that _search is in there. Our SearchQueryBuilder takes care of that, maybe POST vs GET issue? Could that be?

Comment: If I run POST request manually. There is no error and it works. If I run it from code, there is the exception.

Comment: At least that all points to something on the cURL or Neos side going wrong here.

Comment: @user2748323 Do you have any worthy logs from the PHP/Typo3/Neos side?

Comment: I have only the java error from elasticsearch.log (up in the description). There is no other error.